# Flutter: use "children: <Widget>" or "children:"?

Tags: flutter

In this document https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#nesting-rows-and-columns
they use

```
children:
```

But in the Android Studio, and this doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html
they use

```
children: <Widget>
```

So, what are the differences? 
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

both of them are true and worked but the difference is :

it`s like when you create a list, you can create lists like below

```
List<dynamic> list;
List<Widget> list;
```

when you pass the `<Widget>[]` you tell to compiler the input list type is Widget and all list child must be Widget not anything else

and if you use  `children: <Widget>[]` your IDE can know the list type and if you add anything except Widget the IDE throw an error before you build the application and waste your time

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Just want to go further. Beside of widgets, can anything else be  member of that kind of list (after the chidren keyword)?

Comment: the children only can accept a list of widgets, not anything else, and also you can make a list of widget outside of build method and then pass it to children but the list type must be 'widget'

Answer (score 7):

In dart when you want to set type of items in List to do this:

e.g.:

```
var intList = <int>[1, 2, 3];
```

and type of var list become `List<int>`,

So the here in `children` is the same.

set `<widget>` before your widgets list, tell compiler, this list has items with `widget` type.

Answer (score 0):

The first one computes the children in runtime, which might be a cause of very low percentage extra effect on UI rebuilding. Because, it allocates dynamic and in the run time it checks what is the type of my widgets!

On the other hand, Second one is compiled type, which means no extra work for this at the runtime. Which removes the extra pressure on UI rebuilding at the runtime!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.